# Android app shows for lower version than manifest

Tags: android, deployment, sdk

I have released an app on the android market. I am trying to target only android 4.0 and higher. I've set the `minsdkversion` in the manifest to 14. However, when its published to the market, the listing shows "2.3 to 4.2".

Application was built in Android Studio.

What else do I need to do to make it only show up in the market for devices running 4.0 or higher?

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" 
           android:targetSdkVersion="16"
           android:maxSdkVersion="17" />
```

And it does install on devices from the market on lower versions. I have a number of crash reports from android 2.3.7.

Here is my entire manifest file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alford.phase10scorecenter"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"
        android:maxSdkVersion="17"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.alford.phase10scorecenter.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name=".PhaseListViewActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name=".ViewCurrentPhaseSetActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name=".CreateEditPhaseSetActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not re-defining minSdkVersion else where in your manifest? Can you post the whole AndroidManifest.xml? What's the link to your app in Play store?

Comment: Link to the app is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alford.phase10scorecenter

Comment: I don't see any other `uses-sdk` in the manifest. I will try to post the entire manifest.

Comment: If you modified your Manifest file, it takes a few hours to reflect in Google Play store

Comment: I published on Friday, June 14th(so more than 2 days ago) and its been available on lower versions since then.

Comment: Did you develop this on the Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, this is developed in Android Studio.

Comment: How did I only guessed this. I think that this could be the problem. Sometimes AS does not comply with the manifest. What I mean is the following: to eliminate this possibility, thy importing your project in Android SDK. Then, clean, build and produce the .pck file. See if the problem persists.

Comment: @g00dy post that as an answer.  That is the problem. After importing to Eclipse and creating the APK, I uploaded it and the market correctly shows it as 4.0 or greater.  I am logging a bug with Google.

Comment: @Eclipsed4utoo : I think you're not the only one reporting this mess :) Good luck in future projects, have in mind that AS is still in something like a beta ..

Comment: @g00dy what does "thy" mean?

Comment: @blackbelt: It's "try", but I can't edit the comment for some reason.

Comment: @g00dy when you say "try importing your project in Android SDK" you mean in Eclipse ?

Comment: @blackbelt: Well yes.. Or I should have said Android Eclipse SDK or ?

Comment: Android SDK does not make sense. So do you meant "importing your project in Eclipse"?

Comment: I see what you mean and the answer is yes, with the following addition: "importing your project in Eclipse, with the Android SDK installed". If you consider it too long, then use what you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this could be the problem. Sometimes `Android Studio` does not comply with the `AndroidManifest`. What I mean is the following: to eliminate this possibility, try importing your project in `Eclipse` with the `Android SDK` installed as well. Then, clean, build and produce the `.pck` file. See if the problem persists.

Comment: Also wanted to add, currently, Android Studio uses the build.gradle file for the specifying the SDKs.  Not sure if this will change in the future.